# Avoiding type info for the list after serialization in Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a class in C# like below,

```
class Person
{
  List<String> hobbies;
}
```

When I convert it to Java class using Jaxb it looks like

```
class Person
{
  @XmlElement(name = "hobbies")
  ArrayOfString hobbies;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfString", propOrder = {
    "string"
})
public class ArrayOfString {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<String> string;
}
```

All good till now, but now when I am trying to convert this object to Json using Jackson Objectmapper like so,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String jsonString= ow.writeValueAsString(Person);
```

I get the json output as below,

```
{ 
     "hobbies" : { "string" : [ "reading","writing"] }
}
```

Now I need the json to look like below with no string keyword.

```
{ 
     "hobbies" : [ "reading","writing"] 
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot change the c# generated xsd.
Any solutions?

Comment: Note:I was able to solve the issue using the xew plugin in conjunction with xjc which stopped creating extra wrapper classes like ArrayofString above. So need to do any tricks in json serialisation. I would highly recommend using xew plugin as it avoids creating unnecessary wrapper classes which in turn increases your json payloads.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your JAXB part, but if you define your bean classes as:

```
class Person
{
    private ArrayOfString hobbies;

    public ArrayOfString getHobbies() {
        return hobbies;
    }

    public void setHobbies(ArrayOfString hobbies) {
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }
}

class ArrayOfString {

    @JsonValue
    protected List<String> string;

    public List<String> getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(List<String> string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

Note the annotation `@JsonValue` on the field `protected List<String> string`.
Now you will get the expected result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.hobbies = new ArrayOfString();
    person.hobbies.string = Arrays.asList("reading","writing");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String jsonString= ow.writeValueAsString(person);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "hobbies" : [ "reading", "writing" ]
}
```

**Note:** You can still add your JAXB annotations on the beans with no side effect.